# Page transition "jumpy" effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please I really need assistance, concerning a piece of code that I've been trying to fix for a very long time now.

Okay, so it's basically a simple code I wrote in HTML, CSS and JS that involves two pages.

[By default, the second page overlaps the first, but you can simply set the z-index of the first page to be higher so it sits on top of the second, the function will still work.]

NOW THE PROBLEM:

I designed the code such that:

when I click on the body (or document) of the second page, the first page moves to the left (-100vw) and then sits on the second page (0vw, z-index:1)

when I click on the body (or document) of the first page, the second page moves to the right (100vw) and then sits on the first page (0vw, z-index:1)

(I used keyframes in CSS).

When you view the effect in your browser you'll notice that at some point while animating from one page to the other, there will be a "jumpy" effect.

At a point, the animation flows smoothly, then, at another point, it gives this "jumpy" effect
(and that's really annoying)

*Please help me fix this code by removing the "jumpy" effect and making the desired page transition run smoothly.*

Here are the code files (JS,CSS,HTML).

```js
var pg_one = document.getElementById("pg_one");
var pg_two = document.getElementById("pg_two");

pg_one.onclick=()=>{
    pg_two.className = "pg_two";
    pg_one.className = "";
}
pg_two.onclick=()=>{
    pg_one.className = "pg_one";
    pg_two.className = "";
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section#pg_one{
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #5944f0;
    /* z-index: 1; */
}

.pg_one{
    animation-name: p1off;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes p1off {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100vw);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100vw);
        transform: translateX(-100vw);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

section#pg_two{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    background-color: #d0277f;
}

.pg_two{
    animation-name: p2off;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes p2off {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100vw);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100vw);
        transform: translateX(100vw);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section id="pg_one">
        <span>
            <label for="txt">Enter name here:&#xa0;</label><input type="text" id="txt"/>
        </span>
    </section>
    <section id="pg_two">
        <span>
            <label for="pwd">Choose password:&#xa0;</label><input type="password" name="" id="pwd"/>
        </span>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: You should use animation-direction: reverse; when switching pages, so you wont have jumpy, check this pen https://codepen.io/jakegilesphillips/pen/MveNLe

Comment: The blue 'page' comes in smoothly from the left. Are you saying you want the red 'page' to come in from the right?

Comment: YES! a Haworth Yes!

Comment: I want it to come in from the right just like the blue page

Comment: Mind you, initially, it starts from being behind the pink page, then slides left, then slides right (to sit on the pink page). Just as I indicated in the css keyframes, I want the pink page to move right (0vw) and slide in left to sit on the blue page (100vw, z-index 1). The exact opposite of the first.

Comment: @AHaworth were you able to come up with a possible solution?

Comment: I added an answer which is OK assuming I’ve understood the requirement properly.

Comment: @AHaworth Eureka! You've done it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were extra frames in the keyframes definitions which were not needed. In particular moving the element to the left prior to moving it to the right and then bringing it in to the left.

This snippet also removes -webkit- settings just to make it easier to read the CSS, and it makes sure the elements move to z-index 1 right at the start of the animation (otherwise a sligth hesitancy can be seen).

Not needed to solve the problem given in the question, the snippet uses add and remove from classList rather than change the whole classList of an element (just in case in future you want other classes in there as well).

```js
var pg_one = document.getElementById("pg_one");
var pg_two = document.getElementById("pg_two");

pg_one.onclick = () => {
  pg_two.classList.add("pg_two");
  pg_one.classList.remove("pg_one");
}
pg_two.onclick = () => {
  pg_one.classList.add("pg_one");
  pg_two.classList.remove("pg_two");
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section#pg_one {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #5944f0;
}

.pg_one {
  animation-name: p1off;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes p1off {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

section#pg_two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background-color: #d0277f;
}

.pg_two {
  animation-name: p2off;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes p2off {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    rz-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="pg_one">
  <span>
                <label for="txt">Enter name here:&#xa0;</label><input type="text" id="txt"/>
            </span>
</section>
<section id="pg_two">
  <span>
                <label for="pwd">Choose password:&#xa0;</label><input type="password" name="" id="pwd"/>
            </span>
</section>
```